# How can I be sure ajax request and curl request are from the same requester?

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, session

I gonna try to explain my problem.
I use php curl to get a response from an url in cross domain, I pass in this url a key that I check in my symfony controller if it exists in my db. Then I return a response in json. this response allow  to execute an ajax script, this script try to get an other url in jsonp which return a view.

2 virtual hosts : mysite.dev & partnersite.api

```
//in partnersite.api
//httpPost & httpGet are curl functions
//$privateKey => get the key in a DB
$response = httpPost("http://mysite.dev/app_dev.php/api/permission/key", array('private_key' => $privateKey));
// or
$response = httpGet("http://mysite.dev/app_dev.php/api/permission/".$privateKey);
$jsonResp = array();
$jsonResp = json_decode($response, true);
if ($jsonRespP['access'] == 'granted'){
    echo '<script src="'.$jsonRespP['resp'].'" type="text/javascript"></script>';
    //there are some things here ...
    echo '<script>SlAPI({slug : "thing-to-display"});</script>';
}

//in mysite.dev (first controller) 
public function getApiPermissionAction() {
    $response = new JsonResponse();
    //check if key exists in DB and if exists :
    return  $response->setContent(json_encode(array(
        'access' => "granted",
        'resp' => "http://mysite.dev/app_dev.php/api/get_api", 
        //this is ajax script contained in js.html.twig and returning the views of the api
    )));
}

//in js.html.twig
function SlAPI(settings) {
    glob = settings;
    var SlAPI = {
        init: function() {
            if (glob.slug){
                {%  set url = urlSite ~ "/app_dev.php/api/thing/" %}
                url = "{{ url }}"+glob.slug; //==http://mysite.dev/app_dev.php/api/thing/thing-to-display
            }
            ajaxLoadUrl(url);
        }
    }
    SlAPI.init();
}

function ajaxLoadUrl(url, dataValue) {
    var dataValue = (dataValue == undefined ? "" : dataValue); //not used in this case but in others
    url += "?callback=?" ;
    JQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        data: dataValue,
        xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
        jsonpCallback: "successCallback",
    });
}

//in mysite.dev, 2nd controller
// Creating callback response
//$view is a way to a twig
public function callbackResponse($view, $params){
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $response = new Response('', 200, array('content-type' => 'text/javascript'));
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    $response->send();

    if ($request->get('callback')) {
        $arrayNew = array("success" => $this->render($view, $params)->getContent());
        $jsonStr = json_encode($arrayNew);
        echo "{$request->get('callback')}( $jsonStr );";
        exit;
    }
}

//this works
//in partnersite.api I can see my view
```

I need to be sure the both calls are from the same person/computer.

problem is for example, I'm on a computer which can have the key for the first call, I obtain access to display the script, if I have bad intents I can copy the source then give to another person who can display the view and do something I don't want.

I tried to use sessions, but if I create a session in the first controller, I cannot get the same session in the second. IDs are differents (I tried to change it, didn't work). At the 2nd call with ajax there is a phpsessid passed so the session in $request in the 2nd controller is that one.

An other information is the phpsessid doen't change, it's the same when I refresh and with different virtual host (maybe it comes from a cookie), whereas the sessions created change but this is normal, but it could be interresting for you to help me.

```
//following things are examples
//I added an other virtualhost partnersite2.api

//in partnersite.api
//I can start a session 
session_start();
echo session_id(); // hs8teh8qqqksdmj9030buvfpj7
echo '<br />'.$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']; // hs8teh8qqqksdmj9030buvfpj7
// same

//in curl fonction
//I added CURLOPT_COOKIE => 'PHPSESSID=' . $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']

//in mysite.dev (1st controller)
$session = $request->getSession();
$param = $session->getId(); // hs8teh8qqqksdmj9030buvfpj7

//in mysite.dev ajax get (2nd controller)
$session = $request->getSession();
$param = $session->getId(); // 8hmdf2r1imvoc55ioshojdd7i0
$param2 = $request->__toString(); // PHPSESSID: 8hmdf2r1imvoc55ioshojdd7i0

//in partnersite2.api 
session_start();
echo session_id(); // 9crfkb8tnmab04r75gv980dhb7
echo '<br />'.$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']; // 9crfkb8tnmab04r75gv980dhb7
//it's different of when I call from partnersite.api 

//in mysite.dev (1st controller)
$session = $request->getSession();
$param = $session->getId(); // 9crfkb8tnmab04r75gv980dhb7

//in mysite.dev ajax get (2nd controller)
$session = $request->getSession();
$param = $session->getId(); // 8hmdf2r1imvoc55ioshojdd7i0
$param2 = $request->__toString(); // PHPSESSID: 8hmdf2r1imvoc55ioshojdd7i0
//it's same of when I call from partnersite.api 

//Im not sure session is a good way I don't know but may be something processing like a session in server side
// that I can identifie in the both controllers and makes me sure the both requests are from the same computer
```

So my question is, does something exists like a session, that I can initialize in the first controller with an id for example and some parameters and after I'll can get by the id to check if it's the same client who did the both requests ?

I know I can pass by DB but I don't prefer this way, but if I must I will do that.
For example stock in db the timestamp then send it like a public key and pass it in the ajax request then check in db if it exists in db and delete it.,I don't like stock in db because it's temporary. What do you think about that ? may be everything I did it's a wrong way, tell me pl. tx

I hope you gonna understand my problem and excuse my grammar I'm not english ^^ tx

Answer (score 0):

With some rare exceptions, sessions are persisted on the client-side with cookies. These cookies are managed with extended HTTP headers `Set-Cookie` and `Cookie`. These are necessary because, by design, HTTP is stateless.

It's hard to say without seeing any code, but any AJAX requests initiated by the page your server returns should also send along any cookies in the `Cookie` header of that AJAX request, which in turn means even AJAX requests should maintain their cookie-based state with the server.

So, I'm not exactly sure I understand your problem, but you say something along the lines of how you're trying to use sessions for this but can't or that it's not working - I think that's where your debugging needs to start. If your basic session state isn't working properly, they you're likely to have other problems with your application beyond this AJAX one.

Comment: maybe I can change my question in : does something exists to identifie each request curl and ajax from, or how to know in server side if the both requests are from the same computer ?